# moving mesh with rigged bones

Tags: mesh, rigging

I want to make different versions of a rigged character with longer and shorter limbs and other body proportions. is there a way to scale parts of a mesh with its parent bones so i dont have to re adjust the mesh to match again? it gets really tough resizing and repositioning every finger bone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale the bones as desired, select the mesh, in the modifier stack apply the armature modifier, then select the armature in pose mode, select all the bones and choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> "Apply pose as rest pose".

Then select the mesh and add an armature modifier to the mesh and select your armature in the "object" field.

Done.