# Moving bone without affecting skinned Mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I use blenrig 5..

when I skinning I realize that the bone isn't in correct position, i need to fix my bone position without affecting any weighted mesh (skinned mesh)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92861/moving-mesh-with-rigged-bones/92873#92873